# Guardar tabla dinamica laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, table

Tengo un formulario  en donde se ingresan los datos cada hora 8 veces los titulos de la tabla, los cargo dependiendo de la linea carga los titulos.

Quiero guardar esta tabla en la base de datos pero tengo dos dudas:

- ¿Como configuro el controlador para que se sepa donde guardar los datos? Ya que son traidos desde la base de datos
- ¿Como inserto varias filas en mi tabla base de datos? Ya tengo los modelos correspondientes

**imagen de la tabla**
[image: todos los campos son input]

**Blade:** De esta manera cargo los titulos de la tabla

```
@foreach ($flineone as $pro)
  <tr>
    <th class="anchoth" scope="row">{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}</th>
    <td>50</td>
    <td><input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td> 
    <td><input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Controlador:**

```
$one = new lineone();
$one->{$pro->nombre_proceso}= $request->{$pro->nombre_proceso};
$one->save();
```

En mi ignorancia crei esto pero claramente no funciona no se me ocurre como poder guardar esto

Gracias  de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Hice algo parecido con una tabla de roles y accesos, se me ocurre que puedes crear una funcion que te reciba los parametros (ID_FILA, ID_COLUMNA), y que coloques en el id de cada columna su columna + Fila para asi identificarla.

```
<script>
function updateTable(fila, columna){
$.ajax({
let valor = $('#' + fila+ columna).val();
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{route('dynamicTable.update')}}',
                data: {valor:valor,fila: fila, columna: columna},
                success: function (data) {
                     console.log("Dato Actualizado");
                },
                error: function (data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
}
```

Algo asi el foreach

```
@foreach ($flineone as $pro)
  <tr>
    <th class="anchoth" scope="row">{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}</th>
    <td>50</td>
    <td><input onfocusout="updateTable({{$pro->nombre-proceso}}{{$pro->descripcion}}" class="datos" id="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}{{$pro->descripcion}}" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Ya en el controlador solamente haces un update con un where, supongo que a de tener ID esa tabla ala que haces un foreach. Supongo que hay mejores formas quizas de hacerlo pero con lo que describes puedes intentar asi.